# OpenLayers 4 prevent dragging outside bounds in all resolutoins

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I need to constrain the map to only drag within the map view but It also needs to work across multiple resolutions:

```
  var extent = [0, 0, 1685, 895];
  var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    units: 'pixels',
    extent: extent
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
          url: 'assets/img/map.png',
          projection: projection,
          imageExtent: [0, 0, 1685, 895]
        })
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: projection,
      center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
      zoom: 3,
      maxZoom: 5,
      minZoom: 3
    })
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to restrict dragging map by its extent. The only way to restrict is by its center coordinates.

Comment: According to the docs for `ol.View`: `extent ol.Extent | undefined 
The extent that constrains the center, in other words, center cannot be set outside this extent. Default is undefined.` I had assumed u could use this to resolve my issue.

Comment: center is not the boundary as you know. and is changing up to the resolution. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274073/openlayers-min-zoom-to-view-all-map#comment437737_274073 can help you to understand a bit to bypass the problem.

Comment: That's basically what I'm trying to do but I'm not sure how to calculate that `[-7435794.111581946, -8766409.899970295, 8688138.383006273, 9314310.518718438]` in the link you suggested. Obviously you didn't just "know" those numbers, how did you get them?

Comment: If I can understand how to request/calculate those coordinates I can likely update them when the screen changes size as you said, "... and is changing up to the resolution"

Comment: You should manually find the coordinates. one way is by adding click event.

Comment: Right but where do they come from?

Comment: it's from OL and up to the coordinates system you use.

Comment: I see you're using OSM (`new ol.source.OSM`), does that change things since mine is an image? I see that `ol.source.OSM` doesn't have a method to return the coordinates. That's the part I don't get.

Comment: have you tried add click event on the map and checked its parameter returned? there's a coordinates.

Comment: Upon clicking I see I can pull coords via `frameState.viewState.center`. Getting the values with the click event in the map at the top left corner and the bottom right, I was able to keep the maps in bounds. However, when the container size changes the values are no longer valid. Is there a more dynamic way to pull the data. My map will span the width/height of the window.

Comment: try getting `extent` from map zoom property changes